# NavigationView item's not set rtl

Tags: android

i want to create a navigation View in my app. it's open from right. but the menu items are be ltr direction.
how i can set them rtl. also i must to set supportRtl="false" in manifest. so solution except that.

this is activitymain.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>


<include
    layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="right"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:layoutDirection="rtl"
    android:textDirection="anyRtl"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
    app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />
```

and activity_main_drawer.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<group android:checkableBehavior="single"

    >
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_home"
        android:title="@string/nav_home"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_accessibility"


         />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_photos"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_accessibility"
        android:title="@string/nav_photos"
        />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_movies"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_accessibility"
        android:title="@string/nav_movies" />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_notifications"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_accessibility"
        android:title="@string/nav_notifications" />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_settings"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_accessibility"
        android:title="@string/nav_settings" />
</group>

<item android:title="Other">
    <menu>
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_about_us"
            android:title="@string/nav_about_us" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_privacy_policy"
            android:title="@string/privacy_policy" />
    </menu>
</item>
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/lWAic.jpg